# Solving this first order system of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I would like to find the solution (if there is one) of the following system of PDE:
$$ f(x,y)\xi(x,y)=\partial_x f(x,y),\text{ and }f(x,y)\eta(x,y)=\partial_y f(x,y),$$ where $(x,y)\in U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f\in\mathcal{C}^2(U,\mathbb{R})$, as well as $\xi$ and $\eta$. Could somebody provide a method to solve this system or directs me towards some textbook on this topic?

Thank you!

Comment: Are $\xi$ and $\eta$ supposed to be given?  Otherwise you could take $f$ to be any nonzero $C^2$ function and use these equations as definitions of $\xi$ and $\eta$.

Comment: Assuming $\xi, \eta$ are prescribed data and $f$ is positive, you can write this as $\nabla \log f = (\xi, \eta)$, reducing this to the problem of integrating a field to get a potential.

Comment: ... and of course in order for this to work, you need $$\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}$$

Comment: $\xi$ and $\eta$ are prescribed data and I really like the idea to reduce this PDE to the problem of integrating a field to get a potential. @AnthonyCarapetis: Could you make it into an answer please?